# Avoid repeating the same pack number in generate code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have written my project in ASP.NET Core 5. When the user selects the desired pack number, the code is generated manually. The problem is that, for example, when pack 4 is selected twice, the number 4 is repeated twice. Until it has to be repeated only once.

```
protected string GeneratePackingCode(IEnumerable<int> packsNo, IEnumerable<string> companies = null)
{
        if (!packsNo.Any())
            return string.Empty;

        var packingCode = $"Pack:";
        var packs = packsNo
            .OrderBy(e => e);

        var count = packs.Count();

        int first = packs.First(),
        prev = first,
        curr = first;

        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            if (i < count)
                curr = packs.ElementAt(i);

            if (prev + 1 != curr)
            {
                if (first != prev)
                    packingCode += $"{first}:{prev},";
                else
                    packingCode += $"{first},";

                first = curr;
            }

            prev = curr;
        }

        packingCode = packingCode.TrimEnd(',');

        if (companies != null && companies.Any())
        {
            var companiesName = companies
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(e => e)
                .ToList();

            packingCode += $" ({string.Join(',', companiesName)})";
        }

        return packingCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Distinct()` method, imported from `System.Linq` to remove duplicate entries in a `List<T>`.

```cs
using System.Linq;

...

packsNo = packsNo.ToList().Distinct(); // put this on line 4 in your method
```

This way there should only be on entry for every selection, even if a member is selected multiple times.

Comment: No problem! You can kindly tick the checkmark beside this question to accept this answer if it worked out for you.